# Hadoop MultipleOutputFormat.generateFileNameForKeyValue with many keys

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, outputformat

I am trying to play with MultipleOutputFormat.generateFileNameForKeyValue() .

The idea is to create directory for each of my keys.

This is the code:

```
static class MyMultipleTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value, String name) {
        arr = key.toString().split("_");
        return arr[0]+"/"+name;
    }

}
```

This code works only if the emitted records are few. If i run the code against my real input, it just hangs on reducer around 70%.

What might be the problem here - working on small number of keys, not working on many .

Comment: Are you sure the filenames are unique?

Comment: How to ensure that filenames are unique ?
In my understanding name parameter is PART-XXXX which is something i do not control.

arr[0] is a part of the key which is not unique .

My key is : 123456789_timestamp
So the goal is to have directory 123456789/ in the output directory
I think it is somewhat related to not having unique names, but i don't understand why .

Comment: It was just a small thought (if 2 reducers would write to the same file that could be problematic). Since you still use the part-XXXX then I do not immediately have a clue. Can you think of some tests which could provide us with more information?